# IIS external access by IP address

Tags: networking, windows-8, ip, iis-7.5

Can's seem to get this to work. Tried various combinations in Site Bindings. I can view default web page using the internal IP address as well as machine name from any computer on my network, but when it comes to accessing via public IP, which I got from whatismyip.com, browser keeps on waiting and waiting and eventually craps out..

Also, I've disabled Firewall (temporarily), but no luck. I've never done this kind of setup before so, I'm struggling a bit.

My ISP doesn't block traffic on port 80.

All entries in bindings screenshot represent various combinations I've tried either all together or separately..

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some thoughts I have on configuring the resources on your network.

**Configuration Notes**

It looks like you have a router, so it is your router that is bound to the external IP, not your computer. In that case your computer does not have the external IP (75.75.75.75). It only has the internal IP (10.0.0.6). You should set up your router to forward port 80 to your computer's internal IP address. You should bind IIS to the internal IP as well.

I should note that given your screen shots above, that you are close to already doing this. The only thing I would remove from your configuration above is the IIS binding to the external IP (75.75.75.75).

**Testing**

When testing your site, a potential issue is with the router itself. Generally a router will not let an **internal** machine access an **internal** resource (e.g. IIS) via an **external** IP. So for example, if you try to browse from inside your network to 75.75.75.75, the router will not let it happen. That may be why you are seeing the browser hang. What you should do to test the web site is to access the external IP from outside of your network. Have a friend or relative (outside your network) try to connect to the external IP and see if it works.

So how should you access the site from inside your network? Use the internal address only (10.0.0.6).

Comment: It makes perfect sense, chue x. Will check later and let you know.. http://serverfault.com/questions/73208/access-server-behind-router-with-external-ip-works-well-except-from-pc-in-same/73237#73237

Comment: I accessed from my smart phone browser and it works. Doesn't work on same local network as you said.. Thanks.

Comment: You can have a friend or you can use anonymous proxy.  this one for example, http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://75.75.75.75/  change 757575 ip address to whatever you want to access as outside

Comment: or you can add the address in yours `hosts` file so it will not try and go out of your network just to get back in. something like `10.0.0.6 xxxx.com`

Comment: I know this is a late comment.  However, when you said that the "router will not let an internal machine access an internal resource", does that mean I cannot use my public IP from my own computer to access the public site configured on my own machine?

Comment: @Josh your conclusion is generally correct but there are routers that will allow it.

Comment: @chuex Thanks for the reply.  Is there a reason that this is blocked by some routers?  And is there generally a setting one can change to make it work?

Comment: @Josh - the answers to your questions will be router specific.  I don't know why some allow it and others don't.